# Google maps for IE9 in Angularjs App: Unable to get value of the property 'maps'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on an AngularJS app which supports google maps too. Just to avoid extra efforts I am not using any of the angular directives like [angular-google-maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps) or [angularjs-google-maps](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) for this support, just basic map and angularjs. This is what I have in my controller, but I don't think this code is even being executed:

```
$scope.mapContainer = document.getElementById("dfsdfsf");
$scope.options = {
    //some options here
};
$scope.initMap = function(){
    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map($scope.mapContainer, $scope.mapOptions);
};

$scope.initMap();
```

My app works in chrome and firefox but in IE9 I get the following error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'maps': object is null or undefined 
main.js, line 41 character 344
```

I am including the google maps script before other scripts and initializing the map in a controller.

I tried to use the `defer` attribute for the map script to not execute before the whole page is loaded but no difference.

Comment: it would help to see what your code looks like

Comment: @duncan: Added the code, its just creating a new Map instance nothing else. I don't think this code is even getting executed.

Comment: It seems IE9 has problems getting the google API. (since google seems to be null) - Try to re-load the google api. Do you use requirejs? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842507/google-maps-api-v3-doesnt-get-rendered-in-ie9-ie10-firefox-and-chrome-render)

Comment: @Nils:  NO I am not using the require.js, do I need to use it?

Comment: You create a variable called `$scope.options`, but then you pass into the Map constructor `$scope.mapOptions`.  Is this really what you're doing (which would prevent the map loading), or just because you've not pasted your actual code into the question?